# How to repair a rock maple table leaf support

Tags: wood

I have a solid wood old fashioned rock maple dining table with drop leafs on either side. There are 4 supports made of the same wood that can be rotated out to support the leafs when they are up. Today one of the supports split in half when the grand kids were fooling around. How can I repair the support piece? It is a clean break, both edges very smooth. Is there a glue strong enough or is it more complicated? Thanks

Comment: Could be a good question for [Woodworking.SE](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Normal Wood Glue & clamped or strapped (the tough part) for a day or 2 should do the trick. Wipe off any glue that squeezes out with a damp paper towel, sponge or rag immediately.